# Problems With encoding Java Web Project - Using Netbeans 7.3

Tags: java, netbeans, encoding, utf-8, glassfish

Although this theme is recurrent, and even though I'm two days trying to solve this problem so far failed.

I have a web project, created in NetBeans 7.3, using GlassFish 3.1.2, JSF2.0, EJB3.0 and MySQL

I'm at the beginning of the project and have come across this problem which is as follows: When I input some word with á, à, ã, ç, etc on the inputText, this word is stored with bizarre characters in the database. 
What I've done to try to resolve:

1 -) I put the project encode to UTF-8. Right click on project> Properties> Encode = UTF-8. 
2 -) Compile options-enconding = UTF-8. Right click on project> Properties> Compile-encoding = UTF8. 
3 -) vm-options = Dfile.encoding = UTF-8. Right click on project> Properties> Run =-Dfile.encoding = UTF-8. 
4 -) private.properties project netbeans, I added the line: runtime.encoding = UTF-8. 
5 -) changed the netbeans.conf file which is in the installation folder of netbeans, I added the line-J-Dfile.encoding = UTF-8 option in netbeans_default_options. 
6 -) a table in my database is to encode UTF-8

By debug I've checked that by the method that saves the object in the database:

```
public void create(T entity)    
{  
    getEntityManager().persist(entity);  
}
```

no problems with String, ie, with accentuation is ok. The problem happens from now on, where I can no longer debug ...

I edited the connection pool's settings of GlassFish on the admin panel with the property characterEncoding = UTF-8.

And finally I edited the jdbc connecion as jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/igreja?characterEncoding=utf8

I'm going crazy with this bug. Please anyone out there has gone through this?

I thank you in advance!

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.....
I downloaded the multilingual version of GlassFish (glassfish-3.1.2.2-unix-ml.sh)...

And inside the jsf page I did it:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>  
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"           "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">  
    <h:head>  
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />  
    </h:head>  
    <h:body>  
        <f:view encoding="UTF-8">  
            <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8">
```

I hope that this solution could help other users...

Many thanks guys!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm from Mexico, so we use **ñ** and this char doesn't work in other countries so what we do is use `(char)+number` something like this:

```
(char)225 = á
(char)224 = à
(char)227 = ã
(char)231 = ç
```

maybe can help you

Comment: HEY WearFox, tnx for your help. I'm using this line to get the text:      <h:inputText id="nome" value="#{cadastroUsuario.usuario.nome}" title="Nome" required="true" requiredMessage="The Nome field is required."/> Please, tell me, how can I use your solution with my code? Tnx!

Comment: well, in java i use these code:<"ç".codePointAt(0)> it throw a number, it number is combinated with (char), like this "(char)32" you can make a method how convert to char code

Comment: Man, there would exist a better method to solve this. I can't verify each character in a String... I'm speaking here about only a textField but there will be a lot of them...

Comment: If I run a query from netbeans in DB connection like: insert into usuario (nome, login, senha, acesso) values ('Exceção', 'daniel', 'senha', '1');  this is stored perfectly in DB. The problem is when the request is coming from JSF page....

Comment: i will ask a friend, he knows a lot of MySQL, maybe he can help you

Comment: Thank you man, any help will be great.... But I think that the problem is on netbeans or on Glassfish, because as I said if I run this sql command from inside netbeans it works fine....